# Mario wants to return his home quickly

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

Mario is going to his Home.

In his way to home ,there are N-1 friends in N-1 checkpoints.

**Each of his friend is associated with some reputation ,if the reputation of that friend is higher than the reputation of Mario ,he definitely wants to stop and talk to him.**

**If the reputation of the friend less than or equal  to him he  may skip that person and continue his journey.**

In each of his conversation there is a corresponding price and time is associated.

**The time taken in each conversation is absolute difference of reputation.But there is a rule in his society whenever you talks to some one  ,the reputation of both of them become Equal.**

But Mario wants to go his home such that summation of price and time is minimum.

**Price can be negative also.**

Am facing very hard time to solve this problem,
First of all i thought that  we can solve it through DP, but am not able to find it?

**Input**

4(Number of People including Mario)

5(Initial Reputation of Mario)

2 6 2(Reputation of His 3 Friends in Three checkpoints)

2 3 2(Corresponding price  )

**Output**

In optimal case he will skip Friend1 ,but he will definitely talk to his Friend2  (As he has higher reputation than his).It will take time =
|6-5|=1sec .

it will cost him 3.After his conversation his reputation will be 6 then he will skip Friend2.
So optimal answer will be 1+3=4

Comment: Ok as you use `graph` tag so , it's good but is it directed graph , acyclic graph , in otherwords how people are connected with each other? Is the data in grid or serial data?

Comment: It will be directed from left to right.Initially i thought that i will create graph where each node will be connected  every next node until a node with higher height comes and apply a minimum cost traversal from source to destination.

Comment: How does price relate to reputation?  If it's simply the change in reputation, he doesn't stop at all: the reputation gain (negative price) is exactly half the time taken, a net loss.

Comment: A couple of input/desired output examples would help.

Comment: Edited @algrid ,can you help now?

Comment: @Prune Price and reputation is not related .

Comment: Reputation is in range [0, 10^9] inclusively

Comment: How big is N? Would an O(n^2) solution be ok?

Comment: You haven't explained how the two reputations "become equal"; you give only one example, in which Mario acquires his friend's reputation after they talk.  Do they both get the higher reputation?  Do they both get the reputation of the stationary friend?  Is there some other function at work here?

Comment: You've listed a "wants to talk" criterion.  Is this merely a desire, or an algorithmic requirement?  If it's a requirement, then the algorithm collapses to merely satisfying those requirements.  Under what conditions would Mario stop to talk with someone of *lower* reputation?  From what I see above, the algorithm is trivial: stop only when you must and ignore all others.

Comment: Does the reputation gain figure into the optimization at all?